# Correct phone number format for stripe connect node js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

im trying to use the stripe connect api via node js to create a new connect customer however every time i try to add a phone number to the object stripe gives me phone invalid error.
What is the correct phone number format for this request.

iv tried using the phone number in various formats.

```
  const stripe = Stripe('test');
  const opts: any = {
                        type: 'custom',
                        country: 'US',
                        email: user.email,
                        business_type: 'individual',
                        business_profile: {
                            name: user.name.firstName + user.name.lastName,
                            support_email: user.email,
                            support_phone: '+10000000000',
                            support_url: 'https://www.blulight.tech',
                            product_description: 'PicDrip Mobile App'
                        },
                        individual:{
                            phone: "+10000000000",
                            email: user.email,
                            first_name: user.name.firstName,
                            last_name: user.name.lastName,
                            dob: {
                                day: user.dateOfBirth.day,
                                month: user.dateOfBirth.month,
                                year: user.dateOfBirth.year
                            },
                            address:{
                                line1: user.address.line1,
                                line2: user.address.line2,
                                postal_code: user.address.postal_code,
                                city: user.address.city,
                                state: user.address.state
                            },
                            ssn_last_4: user.dateOfBirth.ssn_last_4,
                            verification: {
                                document:{
                                    back:  documents[1].id,
                                    front:  documents[0].id,
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        tos_acceptance: {
                            date: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
                            ip: user.ipAddress
                        }
                    };
                    opts['requested_capabilities'] = ['transfers'];
                    console.log('Stripe customer object ', opts);
                    const customer: Promise<any> = 
                    stripe.accounts.create(
                        opts
                    );
                    return customer.then(
                        (newCustomer: Stripe.accounts.IAccount) => {
                            console.log('Created stripe customer ', newCustomer);
                            return db.collection('stripeCustomers').doc(uid).set(
                                newCustomer
                            ).then(
                                (done:FirebaseFirestore.WriteResult) => {
                                    console.log('Stripe customer added to db ', done);
                                    // return newCustomer;
                                    return stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(
                                        newCustomer.id,
                                        {
                                            external_account: user.bankAccountAuth.id
                                        }
                                    ).then(
                                        (bankAccount: Stripe.bankAccounts.IBankAccount) => {
                                            console.log('Bank account stored ', bankAccount);
                                            return customer;
                                        }
                                    ).catch(
                                        (_error:any) => {
                                            console.log('Error adding bank account to stripe customer ', _error);
                                            return _error;
                                        }
                                    );                            
                                }
                            ).catch(
                                (_error:any) => {
                                    console.log('Error adding stripe customer to db ', _error);
                                    return _error;
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    ).catch(
                        (_error:any) => {
                            console.log('Error creating user ', _error);
                            return _error;
                        }
                    );
                }
            ).catch(
                (_error:any)=> {
                    console.log('Error creating stripe customer ', _error);
                    return _error;
                }
            );
        }
```

the error i keep getting is 
Error: Not a valid phone number at Function.generate (/srv/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:49:16)

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.